# Смазывание текста, когда используется анимация

Tags: html, css

Есть текст, расположенный вертикально

Повернут с помощью `transform: rotate(90deg);`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все хорошо, но когда на странице появляется [анимация](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

То текст смазывается -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Приложите, пожалуйста, код, чтобы можно было в живую увидеть когда смазывается и что вообще у вас там за анимация. В каком браузере смазывается? Информации совсем мало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое поведение есть в некоторых браузерах (в Хроме, например), некоторые вроде как от этого избавились, но общего решения для этой проблемы нет. Причина же таких визуальных эффектов в том, что вы анимируете свойство `transform` — что, кстати, наиболее правильно — а такая анимация происходит отдельным слоем на GPU и с субпиксельным сглаживанием, и именно от применяемого алгоритма в браузере для этого сглаживания зависит будет замыливание или нет.