# transform: scale деформирует текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Писал анимацию для кнопок и столкнулся с проблемой. Когда анимация срабатывает текст на кнопке немного расплывается. Видел в интернете много обсуждений, но решения так и не нашел.

Возможно вы подскажите, как это можно исправить.
Использую вот такую структуру:

```
.ink
    z-index: 100
    display: block
    position: absolute
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)
    border-radius: 100%
    transform: scale(0)
@keyframes ripple
    100%
        opacity: 0
        transform: scale(2.5)
.animate
    animation: ripple .9s linear
```

Ну и вызываю потом просто через `js` добавлением нужного блока с этими классами

js code:

```
//animate start
$('[data-href="#mypres"]:not(.ripplelink)').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.css('overflow', 'hidden');
$this.css('z-index', '0');
var ink, d, x, y;

setInterval(function() {
    if($this.find(".ink").length === 0){
        $this.prepend("<i class='ink'></i>");
    }
    ink = $this.find(".ink");
    ink.removeClass("animate");

    if(!ink.height() && !ink.width()){
        d = Math.max($this.outerWidth(), $this.outerHeight());
        ink.css({height: d, width: d});
    }
    x = Math.round(Math.random()*ink.width() - ink.width()/2);
    y = Math.round(Math.random()*ink.height() - ink.height()/2);
            // y = 0;
            // x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left - ink.width()/2;
            // y = e.pageY - $this.offset().top - ink.height()/2;

            ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");
          }, 3000)
 });
//animate end
```

Comment: предоставьте весь пример для наглядности

Comment: Применяйте деформацию не на саму кнопку, а например на :before или\и :after.
Перенесите стили типа background, border-radius и т.д. на псевдоэлемент, самой кнопке дайте z-index: 1; а псевдоэлементу z-index: -1; тогда текст кнопки будет поверх псевдоэлемента и при добавлении\удалении класса деформируйте его а не кнопку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смазывание текста, когда используется анимация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869539/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)